# Outlook 2010 Crashing Unpredictably

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Very often when I open up Outlook 2010 and start doing actions in it, it will hang and become non responsive.  I have tried letting it finish, but it never does come back (up to 20 minutes of letting it try).  I generally have to restart Outlook and try again.  Usually after about an hour of doing this, Outlook somehow snaps out of it and works for the rest of the day.  It's generally in the morning (though I doubt that's the key variable).  Generally, the emails that cause problems are HTML/formatted, but not always.

What I've done so far to troubleshoot:

- Install Latest Outlook Hotfix (I think Dec 14, 2010)
- Start Outlook in Safe Mode

Neither of those steps seem to make a difference.  Usually - after about 10-15 restarts of Outlook on any given day, then it starts working thereafter.  My next step is to uninstall/reinstall Office 2010, but I'm hoping someone has seen this and knows what to do about it - though not sure.

My configuration is like this:

- Microsoft Online Services (using Microsoft's Sign In App) - Connecting to Exchange
- I have two other Exchange accounts in this profile (new feature in 2010) connected through Outlook Anywhere.
- Life Meeting Conferencing Add In
- I've disabled the People tab/add in.
- I've disabled the "Send to Bluetooth" add-in.

Not sure what else to do?

Comment: Do you have a crash dump? Check the event logs.

Comment: What antivirus are you using? I know this sounds like an odd question but I've seen older versions of AV have problems with Outlook 2010. Try disabling the AV temporarily and see if the crashes stop.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your PST files are ok?
look for a file named SCANPST.EXE in your program files \Microsoft Office\Office14 directory, 
launch it, and have it check and repair your outlook mail files

Answer (score 1):

I had this for months; early mornings were worst. Then one day I noticed it didn't happen. I'd left my phone in the pub (Office is installed on it as well), and its battery had died.  But when I collected it and turned it on, the errors came back.

I looked at the Outlook support page and the only thing I noticed was a switch for stopping reminders from getting tangled up. I closed Outlook and started it from the **Run command**:

```
outlook /cleansniff
```

Since then, no more crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Outlook download all the messages before performing any action on it .I have faced the same trouble too and this seems to help in my case

Comment: @cbkadel : please let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

disable the Microsoft Conferencing Add-On for Microsoft in your Tools Add-Ons.

Make Sure Outlook is shut, then proceed

1. Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > wait for the list of all installed programs to populate the view
2. Right click Microsoft Conferencing Addon For Microsoft Outlook > Uninstall > Yes
   ￼
3. Enter the Administrative username and password to perform the action as shown.
4. Reboot > login > you have now saved time and avoided the Outlook bug (if Outlook crashes at this point, simply open Outlook again, it should be OK)